# I felt injustice after my company hired fresh graduates with higher salary and grade than mine

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise, equality

I don’t know how to explain this situation without looking envious, but I couldn’t handle that new joinees with 0 experience get paid more than i get, they got training outside the country

I already addressed this to my manger one year a go and he told me he will give me a raise but nothing happened so far!

I start to disrespect my management and I think they don’t care about their employees satisfaction at all.

Why I think I deserve a raise:

- I’m given same responsibilities as the new hires, I have more experience but they get paid more!
- My company net profit in 2018 is more than 3 Billion $

What should I do? Should I bring it up to our HR group?

Comment: `What should I do?` - Find a new job which pays according to your contribution and expectation.

Comment: I just joined 2 years ago, I don’t have much experience to look for a new job, I want to build my skills here as my company very reputable one

Comment: Do the new employees have the same education as you and similar grades?

Comment: Yes exact same education and grade

Comment: This is why you should not gossip about salaries with your coworkers. No good will come of it. As for the training question, that is valid for discussion with your manager if you feel you should get some training allocated.

Comment: _my company hired fresh graduates with higher salary_ - Could it be that they are exaggerating their salary? Some people might just be showing off...

Comment: @Brandin well, if OP fights harder for a raise and finally gets a more suitable wage either at her current company or another one, something good would come from it... maybe with some (likely temporary) "bad" as in having to switch jobs or a bit annoyance on the side of her managers.

Comment: You don't know what other experience they have, grades don't reflect everything

Comment: @Brandin, on the contrary, if the OP had never discussed salary with co-workers, they wouldn't realise that they were being taken advantage of, or that they have the opportunity to earn more for the same responsibilities. That's a good thing, from the point of view of the OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 8):

> *I felt injustice after my company hired fresh graduates with higher salary and grade than mine*

You should change your point of view: think this way - Are **you** getting paid enough for the value addition you provide to the organization?

- If you think you deserved to be paid more (based on your work and performance), go ahead and ask for it. If the organization is not willing to revise, and you feel you **should** be paid more, you need to find a new organization which will pay you that amount.
- If you think based on your contribution your paycheck is proportionate, and/or you cannot justify the ask for a raise / revision based on **your contribution**, then, asking for a raise based on some other employee's payout is not going to do any good, rather it will paint you in a bad light.

**Moral of the story:** How much you are getting paid is of your interest, not how much others are getting paid.

> *I already addressed this to my manger one year a go and he told me he will give me a raise but nothing happened so far!*

[Very useful suggestions on asking for a raise if you feel you are underpaid.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1025/61983)

> *I start to disrespect my management and I think they don’t care about their employees satisfaction at all.*

No good will come from an engagement where either party is not *happy*. If you feel you have enough reasons to be paid more, and all your efforts in conveying that is not working, you need to look for a new job then.

> *What should I do? Should I bring it up to our HR group?*

I personally don't think the HR really has anything to do / say in this. It's very likely they'll reinforce your manager / supervisor's decision.